# Why are Newton polygons only ever treated over complete DVRs?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring, and $f(x) := c_nx^n + \cdots + c_1x + c_0\in R[x]$ a polynomial with $c_nc_0\ne 0$. Then the newton polygon of $f(x)$ is the lower convex hull of the points $(i,\text{ord}(c_i))$ in the plane, which is a union of line segments of slope $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_k$, and let $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k$ be the length of their projections onto the $x$-axis.

Then the theory of the newton polygon says that for $i = 1,\ldots,k$, $f(x)$ has precisely $\mu_i$ roots of valuation $-\nu_i$.

This statement (and its proof) seems to make perfect sense without ever assuming that $R$ is complete. So why is it that every reference I can find on newton polygons assumes $R$ complete? (Is there perhaps some deeper results on Newton polygons that require this?)

Comment: You can complete.

Comment: The theory of Newton polygons says that $f(x)$ has precisely $\mu_i$ roots of valuation $-\nu_i$ *in a complete algebraically closed overfield*.

Comment: @CaptainLama I'm pretty sure the proof makes sense for the algebraic closure of its fraction field

Comment: This does not make sense to me : if your original ring is not complete (in fact, Henselian), there will be infinitely many valuations on the algebraic closure extending your valuation.

Comment: Actually after some more thought it does make sense : all the choices valuations on the algebraic closure will just permute the values on the roots of the polynomial, but the number will be the same. This being said, I think this is the reason of the restriction to the complete case : so you can speak of *the* extension of the valuation to the algebraic closure without ambiguity.